# Is it possbile to send/receive short videos using Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I would ask whether it is possible to send/receive short videos using Kafka.

I am receiving video and also video metadata information from other team. Each video is about 20M-30M.

I would ask whether it is possible to send video and its metadata using Kafka, that is, each message maybe 30M. Are there possible limitations using this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use Kafka for transferring messages that are 30M large. We have done this with XMLs that are over 50M on our production system and it is still running fine.

However, it is highly recommended to **not** significantly exceed the default size of 1M as Kafka it optimizied for small messages. The throughput abilities will suffer if large messages will get replicated and acknowledged over the cluster and usually the compression is more effective when dealing with many small similar looking files than with one large file.

Maybe choosing the right compression type in your case can decrease the size of a video and bring the size down.

The Confluent consultants suggested to keep the max.message.bytes on the broker below 5M.

**Edit:**

As a caveat, changing the configuration allowing larger (than 1M default size) files to be stored in Kafka is a broker wide setting. So it impacts also your use cases with smaller files in case you are sharing your Kafka cluster.

In that case, what I have seen if you have e.g. HDFS and/or Hbase available you could store the video there and simply have the link or rowkey stored in Kafka.

Comment: Thanks @mike for the helpful anwser!